# Display Texture in viewport

Tags: modeling, texturing, image, unity

I am new to using Blender 2.8. Actually to Blender as a whole. I am creating a game in unity and needed a .obj file. Currently I have an obj file, but is has no colour at all. It's just plain white. The textures(.png files) came separately unfortunately and I have to join them myself. The problem is though when I import the obj files I can see the design in shader view, but not in the viewport. And so I can not see any colours when I export it. I don't know how to make Blender export the version I see in Shader View, not in the ViewPort. I have attached some pictures to make it clear. Please remember that I just started using Blender and have no experience. I just want to use Blender to add the texture to the obj file. I took some time on other sites for help, but there were too confusing for me(since I am still new to Blender). I would appreciate an answer that I can understand. [image: Image in Shader View]

I can't seem to upload the view from the viewport, but it is the same model, but without colours. Can anyone help me or point me in the direction on how I should fix this?

Link to file example
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/136JAU39QuD3YjroLCU9UfEzixqg6PBRa?usp=sharing

Comment: You can display textures in solid viewport by clicking on the drop down arrow in the top right of the 3d view then you'll be presented with a few options, in the color choices you should select Texture. Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem's issue is that you are in the view <kbd>Material Preview</kbd> instead of the correct view <kbd>Rendered View</kbd>.

You can also easily toggle these views with the <kbd>Z</kbd> key shortcut menu.

[image]

Comment: Hi, It seems like I may have confused you and Gorgious. I can click z and switch the the dev view and I can see the colour. The problem is I can't export it with the shader as an obj. It is just a blank file. This is a big problem for me in Unity. I have to create a new material for each material that exists that uses that png texture. So I need to create 20 new materials and assign them the png in Unity. I wanted a way to do that quickly in Blender. That way when I export as an obj I can just use that in my project, without creating any new materials.

Comment: The routine of needing to recreate materials for exported .obj files is quite normal I believe... Have you tried other supported formats such as the .fbx format?

Comment: Yeah, I tried fbx, but it still doesn't work. All of my other assets came with the material. That's why I thought I could export with the correct material, not the blank one. If it isn't possible I guess I could just manually recreate the materials.

Comment: The only other format I could think of that would be useful to this particular scenario would be the "glTF" format. Blender already has natively import/export capabilities for it, and Unity supports them too.

Comment: Ok, I will try using that format tommorow. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Apologies that I do not have a straight-up answer for your problem's issue. :)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not replying earlier, but it seems gITF is a format that Unity does not support. I should note though that when I drag the file to [link](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/), I can see the tank with full colour.

Comment: Ok, So I just updated my post with a link to a file example. It might help you figure out what my problem is. If not I will have to manually create the textures in Unity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm... This is awkward, apparently Unity doesn't support the .gltf format "officially," but does unofficially through 3rd-party plugins such as this one: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF

Answer (score 0):

In order to output FBX textures to UNITY, it is
It is recommended to internalize the texture information into FBX beforehand.

Try this method.

### **Setting up the blender material**

[image]
As a reminder, you need to make sure that the texture is properly saved in a folder somewhere.

### **FBX Settings**

[image]

Store the textures inside the FBX file.
Keeping the texture inside (COPY) will increase its versatility.

### **Setting up UNITY**

[image]
Output the image and material information inside FBX in UNITY.

If you want to extract only the texture, you can use only the texture.
If you want to set the material settings, press the Extract Material button as well.

[image]

If you want the transparent color to be reflected on UNITY, change the rendering mode.
Change the "rendering mode".
[image]
If you want to set up a normal map, add a normal map node in between.